# Spatial join to append which multi polygon a point is in (GeoPandas)

Tags: geopandas, spatial-join, within

Currently I have around 40 lists of coordinates I need to run the same operation on:

- What we will call the the points data, A)
- With one list of multi polygons (The polygon data, B).

I need to take each of those 40 lists of ~400k points, and add on which of the 1200 some polygons it is within into a new column. I know it's a spatial join that should be using within or contains but would someone mind telling me which op and how statement I should be using? Taking more time than I care to admit already and I just gave up and started doing it in QGIS to meet the deadline, but still want to be able to learn what I need to do going forward.

Comment: The polygons are non overlapping?

Comment: I believe a small amount of overlap may exist between them. I would hope not but I also think the engineers might have coded in a small amount of overlap as a margin of error.

Comment: Are each list 400k points or 10000 points in each

Comment: Each list is 400k. It would probably be easier to think about it at 40 reruns of similar operations, partially why I don't want to use qGIS in the future vs just writing a script to run over the set and I can walk away for 3 hours while it runs instead of manually doing each datasets join.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to adapt to work with your lists. Each spatial join takes ~0.3 seconds for 400k points and 1200 rectangular polygons.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

polys = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/1200_rects.shp')

#Create some test point data
ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = 6249983,179674, 7452548,839177 #Extent to create points within
xlist = np.random.uniform(low=xmin, high=xmax, size=(40, 400000)) #Create an array with 40 rows and 400000 random values in each row
ylist = np.random.uniform(low=ymin, high=ymax, size=(40, 400000))

for row in range(xlist.shape[0]):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    coords = np.column_stack((xlist[row], ylist[row])) #Zip the two arrays
    points = pd.DataFrame(coords, columns=['x','y']) #Create a pandas df
    points['geometry'] = gpd.points_from_xy(x=points['x'], y=points['y'], crs="epsg:3006") #Create a geometry column
    points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points) #Convert df to gdf
    joined = gpd.sjoin(left_df=points, right_df=polys[["polyuuid","geometry"]], how="left", predicate="intersects") #I only need the polyuuid column
    print(f"Time elapsed: {(datetime.datetime.now()-start).total_seconds()}")
    #Time elapsed: 0.282484
    #Time elapsed: 0.399579
    #Time elapsed: 0.363134

#joined.shape
#Out[56]: (400888, 6) #888 extra rows Due to overlapping polygons

#joined.head()
#                x  ...                              polyuuid
# 0  545148.289561  ...                                   NaN
# 1  216695.633557  ...                                   NaN
# 2  605705.282340  ...                                   NaN
# 3  457599.469253  ...  9a854019-4ad8-4024-a2fc-8d5f37fb4e97
#First three points are not intersecting any polygon

#Handle duplicates. Sort by some logic, then drop duplicates
#joined = joined.sort_values('polyuuid', ascending=False, na_position='last')
#joined = joined.drop_duplicates(subset='pointid', keep='first')
```

[image]